# Why does natural counting with a gamma spectrometer differ from Neutron activation analysis?

Tags: experimental-physics, research-level, radiation, radioactivity, data-analysis

As stated in the title, why are the data from natural counting using s gamma spectrometer different than the data from neutron activation analysis using the same samples?

Answer (score 1):

Neutron activation induces radioactivity in the sample that wouldn't have been there without it. What you are counting are the unstable nuclei that the method creates, rather than the ones that have been in the sample, already.